# How to get the number of contributors of Github repositories using Github API and PyGithub package

Tags: github-api, pygithub

I am using following code to get the number of contributors of a repository

```
from github import Github
g = Github("*****github Access token****")
repo = g.get_repo('mui-org/material-ui')
contributors_count = repo.get_contributors().totalCount
```

It is giving number of contributors as 443, however, the correct number of contributors on the github website is 1077.

Can some one tell why am I getting different values?

Also, is there any other function in PyGithub to get correct number of contributors?

Answer (score 1):

I'm bumping up against this too. I'm pretty sure the difference in the the counts is including or excluding "anonymous contributors". The [GitHub endpoint accepts an `anon` param](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors) that can be set to `True`.

Looking at its [source](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/ff789dcc819ecaf79ab208f5c9c168b58ea349e6/github/Repository.py#L1802), PyGithub doesn't accept any arguments for its `get_contributors` method, so it doesn't currently surface anon contributors. It could be forked or patched to take it.

For my needs, I'm going to write my own method that makes a request for a repo, parses the "last" relation from the `Link` header and calculates based on the number of results on the last page. Still writing it, so I don't have a code sample for now.

Sorry I don't have anything more actionable for the moment.

Comment: It works now https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/Repository.py#L1989

Answer (score 0):

This has been added since to PyGitHub. Now you just simply have to do:

```
repo.get_contributors(anon="true")
```